# Adding elevation to a path to visualize aerial tracks over terrain?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

[This example shows a path snapped to the terrain.](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/query-terrain-elevation/) Is there a way to set the elevation along a path?

[Ayvri is a good example of generally what I'd like this to look like, but customizable with mapbox.](https://ayvri.com/scene/85qdyvgpj4/ckq13jkw30000435b9jzhqkda)

Comment: The documentation does not seem to have any references to elevation.
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#marker#setlnglat

Comment: You can do something similar in Mapbox with [threebox](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox) check the [example 19](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox/tree/master/examples#19-fixedzoomhtml) out

Answer (score 1):

You can probably convert your line into a polygon, then use a `fill-extrusion` layer to show something like this. It may not look good. I have a vague memory that Mapbox had a demo of something like this way back in the day when they had a `surface` API which gave the elevation at a point (prior to their current method)>